# How to merge several json files into one using python

Tags: python, json

I have 6 json files that I would like to merge into one. I know I need to use glob, but I am having trouble understanding how to do it. I have attached the names of the files and the code I have tried. I have also created an empty json file called 'merge.json' that I would like all the jsons to be merged into. They all have the same dictionary keys, but I would like to simply merge the files, not merge all of the values into one key. I have attached what the data looks like and what I would like it to look like when merged. Thank you!

```
file1 = 'file1.json'
...
file6 = 'file6.json'
```

file1:

```
{time:12, 'sizes':[1,2,3], 'scores':[80,100,77]},{time:42, 'sizes':[2,3,1], 'scores':[90,50,67]},{time:88, 'sizes':[162,124,1], 'scores':[90,100,97]}
```

file2:

```
{time:52, 'sizes':[192,242,3], 'scores':[80,100,77]},{time:482, 'sizes':[2,376,1], 'scores':[9,50,27]},{time:643, 'sizes':[93,12,90], 'scores':[10,400,97]}
```

...

merged:

```
{time:12, 'sizes':[1,2,3], 'scores':[80,100,77]},{time:42, 'sizes':[2,3,1], 'scores':[90,50,67]},{time:88, 'sizes':[162,124,1], 'scores':[90,100,97]},{time:52, 'sizes':[192,242,3], 'scores':[80,100,77]},{time:482, 'sizes':[2,376,1], 'scores':[9,50,27]},{time:643, 'sizes':[93,12,90], 'scores':[10,400,97]}
```

I saw on another thread to use:

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

But I do not understand what goes in "*.json", and where the files are being called. Thank you!

Comment: Those aren't actually valid JSON files. It looks like you're just treating them as text files and trying to concatenate them all to a new file. Anyhow, what is going wrong with your attempt to enumerate the JSON files?

Comment: The `glob glob("*.json")` is generating the pathbame of all the files in the current directory ending with .`.json`. So as long as you put the json files in the same directory than your script that should work.

Comment: @jarmod Is there a way to still merge them into a json?

Comment: @YacineMahdid Ok, thank you!

Comment: As mentioned, you can put the path to the json files in the glob. `glob("path/to/*.json")` would be relative to the current directory. You can get more creative by using "~" for your home directory and also environment variables,  but you need tools like `os.path.expanduser()` and `os.path.expandvars`.

Comment: The updated samples are harder to deal with than the original. You have independent json objects separated by commas, A single json object would have angle brackets around  the dicts to make it a list. E.g, `[{time:12, 'sizes':[1,2,3], 'scores':[80,100,77]},{time:42, 'sizes':[2,3,1], 'scores':[90,50,67]}, ...]`.

Comment: And tell us about the directory these json files are in. Is it the current working diretory? Is it relative to your home directory?

Comment: I need to figure out the actual format of the json, I will update it as soon as possible! My apologies!

Comment: @tdelaney FYI ‘[]’ are square brackets (indicating an array or list), rather than angled brackets (which are ‘<>’).

Comment: @jarmod - good point!

Comment: Be sure to post valid test data. Your JSON needs to use double quotes, all strings need to have double quotes around them and the outer list [..]`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets turn this into a full working program using argparse so that files can be specified on the command line. Then the decision of which directory holds the desired JSON files can be decided at run time and you can use the shell's globbing to list them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Read a list of JSON files holding a list of dictionaries and merge into
a single JSON file holding a list of all of the dictionaries"""

import sys
import argparse
import json

def do_merge(infiles, outfile):
    merged = []
    for infile in infiles:
        with open(infile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infp:
            data = json.load(infp)
            assert isinstance(data, list), "invalid input"
            merged.extend(data)
    with open(outfile, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfp:
        json.dump(merged, outfp)
    return 0

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('outfile', help="File to hold merged JSON")
    parser.add_argument('infiles', nargs='+', help="List of files to merge")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    retval = do_merge(args.infiles, args.outfile)
    print(f"Merged {len(args.infiles)} files into {args.outfile}")
    return retval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    retval = main(sys.argv[1:])
    exit(retval)
```

With sample JSON files setup as

mytest/file1.json

```
[{"time": 12, "sizes": [1, 2, 3], "scores": [80, 100, 77]},
{"time": 42, "sizes": [2, 3, 1], "scores": [90, 50, 67]},
{"time": 88, "sizes": [162, 124, 1], "scores": [90, 100, 97]}]
```

mytest/file2.json

```
[{"time": 52, "sizes": [192, 242, 3], "scores": [80, 100, 77]},
{"time": 482, "sizes": [2, 376, 1], "scores": [9, 50, 27]},
{"time": 643, "sizes": [93, 12, 90], "scores": [10, 400, 97]}]
```

And the test

```
~/tmp$ ./jsonmerge.py mergedjson.json mytest/*.json
Merged 2 files into mergedjson.json
```

Comment: Thank you! The json file is actually not separated by lines, I will edit this! Is there still a way to do this?

Comment: @supercool - yes, and it will likely include a list like your original.

Comment: @supercool - the format you showed is rather common, so I answered that way.

Comment: @tdelaney guess my rudimentary prior take on the same deserved a comment

Answer (score 0):

Put all your JSON files under one directory and run this code in the same directory

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

This will produce a `merged_file.json` which will contain merged data from all JSON files.

`for f in glob.glob("*.json")` will iterate through every json file in that directory in the order they are present in directory.

Comment: `json.load` won't work on the data as presented and `append` may not be the best choice either. We are waiting for an update from OP to figure out the best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like below, Check the repl.it [code](https://repl.it/repls/MuffledDarkkhakiDisc) -

```
import glob

a = glob.glob('./*.json')
print (a)

merged = open("merged.json", "w+")
for i in a:
  with open(i, "r") as f:
    for j in f.readlines():
      merged.write(j)

merged.close()
```

Comment: `./*.json` is the same as `*.json`. Both reference the current working directory.

Comment: Yes it is current directory, where you are running the `python ./jsonmerge.py `
What is your requirement ? do you want to create merged file on some other path ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use the merged json as a valid json then you must structure it well. (This assumes that individual jsons are valid jsons):

Working on @tdelaney's answer:

```
with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write("[")
    counter=1
    for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            line = None
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
            if line is not None and not line.endswith(b"\n")
                outfile.write(b"\n")
            if counter < len(glob.glob("*.json")):
                outfile.write(",")
            else:
                outfile.write("]")
            counter=counter+1
```